# Minimal backups of a Debian server

Tags: backup, debian

I have a shiny new Debian server running in an Amazon EC2 instance. I've spent a while setting it up and it now works nicely. However, because it's a cloud server, if I (or someone else) presses the wrong button then its virtual hard disk will go pop and I have to do it all over again. So, I want to make backups.

But I'm paying by the byte for storage, so I want to make a *small* backup.

It should be possible to backup a complete Debian server by recording the set of currently installed packages (which I can do via `dpkg --get-selections`), the state of the debconf database (which I can do via `debconf-get-selections`), and then only backing up files that cannot be trivially replaced from the packages --- i.e., everything else. Then restoring the backup should be a matter of reinstalling the packages and dropping the files on top.

This is precisely the sort of thing I don't want to do myself because I'll get it wrong. Are there any tools to allow me to do this?

(Note: I'm not looking for an incremental backup solution. I want to take a complete snapshot.)